# Lenovo webcam ignores blue color

Tags: windows-7, skype, webcam, lenovo-laptop

By software based error, my webcam often sets itself to ignore blue in my room. If I force different resolution then 640x480, the problem is fixed. But if I return back to normal resolution, the camera us blue-blind again.

1. How do I prevent it?
2. Can this by a hardware error?

I don't know what debug info should I post here - just that I'm using Lenovo Ideapad Z560 under Windows 7. I'm streaming the camera using application based on OpenCV framework - but the same behavior applies to Skype and other programs.

Comment: Could you describe how it ignores the blue areas?

Comment: Not areas - it ignores blue channel of RGB. If you take photo in your computer and remove blue channel, you will see what I see - greeny yellow picture.